# How does sqoop handle SQL Server DB locks?

Tags: database, hadoop, sqoop

On the subject of importing data into sqoop from Microsoft SQL Server. How does sqoop handle database locks when running import table commmands?

More info:

Sqoop is using a JDBC driver.

Comment: [@Marc_S] can you undo your edits? I asked about MS SQL server specifically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sqoop handles database locks by taking required locks and respecting conflicting locks acquired by other processes. Same as everybody else.

What exactly are you worried about? Sqoop does ordinary `INSERT` operations.

Comment: Reading from the database creates a shared lock. Does creating a shared lock for a long time impact the database? Please expand on what type of concurrency control is used by the Sqoop utility.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175519(v=sql.105).aspx